# Averages not calculating correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, time, average

I've got a timer app that saves the times in milliseconds to an array then formats them to larger units of time and displays them in a table.

Now I'm calculating the average of the most recent 5 times (in milliseconds) then formatting that number to larger units of time and displaying it to the table as well, but I'm running into a math issue that I can't solve.

Say my time array has five entries.

```
[10069, 14062, 15060, 13033, 13094]
```

So the average of these five times is 13,396 (all five added together minus the highest and lowest and divided by 3). However, when converted to time strings, these times are as follows:

```
[10.69, 14.62, 15.60, 13.33, 13.94]
```

And if you calculate the average of these five numbers the same was as above, you get an average of 13.96 when it should be 13.396, which would be rounded up to 13.40.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

---

Below is part of the function that takes in milliseconds and returns a string formatted with larger units of time. So passing in 1077 SHOULD return 1.07 but instead it returns 1.77 instead.

```
milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 100)),
seconds = parseInt((duration / 1000) % 60),
minutes = parseInt((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
hours = parseInt((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
```

Below here is the timeFormatter that's within the timer.js file that takes in the milliseconds that have passed between starting and stopping the timer and displays them as a string. I think this one is doing it's job, but it's hard to say. When the timer reads 1.77, the number that goes into the array is 1077 when it should be 1770.

```
function timeFormatter(timeInMilliseconds) {
    var time = new Date(timeInMilliseconds);
    var minutes = time.getMinutes().toString();
    var seconds = time.getSeconds().toString();
    var milliseconds = Math.floor(time.getMilliseconds().toString() / 10);

    if (milliseconds < 10) {
        milliseconds = '0' + milliseconds;
    }

    if (minutes < 1) {
        return seconds + '.' + milliseconds;
    } else {
        if (seconds < 10) {
            return minutes + ':0' + seconds + '.' + milliseconds;
        } else {
            return minutes + ':' + seconds + '.' + milliseconds;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Actually, I think the problem is in the toMS function that is taking in the formatted time string I send to it (10.77) and returning milliseconds. If I pass in 10.77, it returns 1077 when it should return 1770, right?

```
function toMS(str) {
    if(str.includes(":")) {
        const [mins, secms] = str.split(":");
        const [sec, ms] = secms.split(".");
        return ((+mins * 60) + +sec) * 1000 + +ms;
    } else {
        const [sec, ms] = str.split(".");
        return (+sec) * 1000 + +ms;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to say since you didn't post any code

Comment: where do you get `13.396` from?

Comment: the second array should be [10.069 , 14.062 , 15.060 , 13.033 , 13.094] , then the average will be 13.396

Comment: @NinaScholz "all five added together minus the highest and lowest and divided by 3"

Comment: That doesn't explain how `13094` relates to `13.94`. Seems more like a conversion problem. Show us your code as per [mcve]

Comment: what is the purpose of this calculation, I am so confused

Comment: As Ali says, you are doing a bad conversion to decimals.  `10069` and `10.69` have no meaningful relationship.  So what do you mean by "time strings"?

Comment: After looking some more I think you guys are right that my conversion is wrong. I've updated the question with my new timeFormatter function and some more problems.

Comment: Why do questions get so much attention in the first 10 minutes and then they die and never get any more answers???

Comment: Because people like shiny objects.

Comment: Please don't edit to ask a different question.  Start a new one instead.

Comment: Please help. Pretty sure it's a problem with the toMS function I just posted.

Comment: What does your formatted timeString represent?  `10.77 -> 1770` would be really weird.  But I don't know what `10.77` represents.  Is it just seconds, with a decimal?  If so, then `10.77 s -> 10770` would be correct.  (Just multiply by 1000.)

Comment: Also, about "please help."  This is run by a collection of volunteers who look in when they have the time and the inclination.  I happened to leave this window up when I left for a meeting, and came back to it later.  Otherwise, unless you mentioned my name (like @Treedot), I might never look at this question again.

Comment: please add some data and the wanted result.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Sorry I meant to write that 10.77 is 10 seconds and 770 milliseconds. Also, I tried to make a new post but I am only allowed to every 90 minutes.

Comment: @NinaScholz I've got some in there now. The function I added to the bottom, when I pass in 10.77 (10 seconds, 770 milliseconds) it should return 1770 but instead it returns 1077.

Comment: 10.77 should return 10770 (10 seconds = 10000 ms)

Answer (score 0):

So as has been commented on, those numbers you had in ms should be:
[10.069, 14.062, 15.060, 13.033, 13.094] in seconds, and if you do your(sum-min-max)/3 thing on them you do get 13.39633333, which converted back to seconds agrees with your original calculation (13396 to the nearest integer). As you discovered, it is a conversion problem.
Your line `milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 100)),` seems like it should be `milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 1000)),` In the example of 1077, it does not matter, but for 1977 it does (That is a full a second and 977 ms). The other parts there appear correct.

In the formatter, `if (milliseconds < 10) {
        milliseconds = '0' + milliseconds;
    }`should be `if (milliseconds < 10) {
        milliseconds = '00' + milliseconds;
    }//7 ms=.007 s
else if (milliseconds < 100) {
        milliseconds = '0' + milliseconds;//97 ms =.097 s
    }`

Finally, in your toMS function, before the return, you need to handle the possibility that ms was 1 or 2 characters long number (for simplicity I will assume all times were truncated or rounded, and it could not be a 4 digit number -- this appears to be justified based on your use of floor above). .007 is indeed 7 ms, but .7 is 700 ms and .77 is 770 ms. So you need to add in `ms=(ms+'00').slice(0,3)` before your return lines.

I believe taken together, these should address the issues (though I might have missed something).

Comment: I am assuming 1:24.56 means "and .56 of a second" not "and 56 ms." I also posted this before knowing it had been answered (potentially better) in a related post.